# vue test return error wrapper.findComponent is not a function

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vue-test-utils

I have a test in Vue:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import InputComponent from '@/modules/nsignalsimfrontend/components/inputs/InputComponent'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'

describe('InputComponent.vue', () => {
    it('test', async () => {
        const $t = () => {}
        const value = 'Foo'
        const wrapper = shallowMount(InputComponent, {
            mocks: { $t },
            propsData: {
                value,
            },
        })
        
        expect(wrapper.props().value).toBe(value)

        const input = wrapper.findComponent({ ref: 'input' })
        input.element.value = value
        await input.trigger('keyup.enter')

        expect(wrapper.emitted().submit).toBeTruthy()
        expect(wrapper.emitted().submit[0][0]).toEqual(value)
    })
})
```

When I run this test in local, work correctly, but when I try build application by Jenkins (in build I have `npm run test:unit`) I have an error:

> wrapper.findComponent is not a function

I have @vue/test-utils version 1.0.3

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with @vue/test-utils from 1.0.0-beta.29, but you can use wrapper.find() to select by ref.
example: wrapper.find({ ref: 'input'})
If you want to find by component you can just wrapper.find(Component)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Upgrading @vue/test-utils from 1.0.0-beta.31 to 1.1.2 solved it for me.